# Slick slider next is not working in image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

Slick slider next is not working in image but works fine in video.

This is the link : [Click](https://cutt.ly/jj4avsfI)

```
$('.autoplay').slick({slidesToShow: 1,slidesToScroll: 1,autoplay: true,arrows:true,dots:false,autoplaySpeed: 7000,infinite: true,fade: true,cssEase: 'linear'});
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because you have errors in you console...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (custom.js:24)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Slick.postSlide (slick.js:1474)
    at slick.js:2212
```